# Работа с API SCP SL

Tags: php, html, api

У меня есть api ключ https://api.scpslgame.com/serverinfo.php?id=21204&key=8pN3t%2FgTR8Il9PIcJr%2FB2GMz&players=true .
Он выдаёт данные о сервере, порт, кол. игроков.
Я не понимаю как прочитать и выдать данные с этого API.
Мой Код Выглядит сейчас вот так:

```
$server_info = json_decode($response, true)['Servers'][0];
$players_count = explode('/', $server_info['Players']);
```

Comment: А что именно вы не можете понять?

Comment: Ну, так у Вас сейчас в `$server_info` массив. Просто добавьте ещё один ключ при получении значения. Например `json_decode($response, true)["Servers"][0]["Players"]`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$data = file_get_contents(
    'https://api.scpslgame.com/serverinfo.php?id=21204&key=8pN3t%2FgTR8Il9PIcJr%2FB2GMz&online=true');
$json = json_decode($data); 
$date = json_decode($response,true)['Servers'][0]; 
$players_count = explode('/', $date['Players']);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.